# Replacing <hr> line with with a custom glyph

Tags: css, markdown, pseudo-element, typography

I would like to replace horizontal line rendered by default by the `<hr>` tag with three asterisks (horizontally centered). If possible, I want to achieve this **with pure CSS**, specifically:

- I don't want to touch my markup, there should be just plain `<hr>`, no helper divs or anything like this (because I'm styling Markdown files);
- no background images;
- no Javascript.

First I tried:

```
hr {
    width: 0;
}

hr:before {
    content: "***";
}
```

and it *almost* does the trick, but I want it centered, and have no idea how to center it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Browsers display `<hr>`s using borders, so:

```css
hr {
    border: none;
}

hr::before {
    content: '***';
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Slap a `text-align:center` on your psuedo-element.